# Urdu Phonetic 1.0 in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support

I use to work a lot with the Urdu language in my office. I got some homework and I tried to type some Urdu in LibreOffice but the keyboard layout is completely changed. I can't find many of the symbols on the keyboard and there are some Urdu words on the wrong buttons.

I want this keyboard layout in Ubuntu. Can I get this?

[image: Image showing my expected behavior]

Comment: Did you find anything ?

Comment: In Deepin OS, its name is Urdu (Pakistan).

Answer (score 5):

The steps below worked for me perfectly.

**I am using Ubuntu 15.10 Gnome 3.16**

1. Settings
2. Keyboard
3. Input Sources
4. Press + button and add "Urdu(Phonetic)"
5. Open any application to write with URDU(Phonetic) Layout.
6. You can easily change your input sources(Keyboard Layouts) from top right corner of the screen.

Comment: worked perfectly on Ubuntu 20.04. I would like to add shortcut key change the keyboard language. It's WindowsKey + Space

Comment: Not working on ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

There a bug submitted before, The keyboard issue was a part of it. There 6 layouts for Urdu in Ubuntu mentioned here [+bug/1153188/comments/3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/+bug/1153188/comments/3).

Could you help test all of them (don't just look on names)?

And please, tell us:

- Which keyboard you were looking for from them?
- Is it not one of them? so which one of them is most close/similar to the one you are looking for? and honestly if you can provide a clear screen-shot of the difference, that will be GREAT.
- Is that keyboard you are looking the most used in your country (Pakistan, right?)? So should it be the default in Ubuntu?

I hope you can answer each question I asked, I really mean it. I'm an Arabic user and that bug was stuck needing kind of advanced Urdu user.

Answer (score 0):

The steps below worked for me correct.

**I am using Ubuntu 21.10 64-bit**

1. Settings.
2. Keyboard.
3. Click + in Input Sources.
4. Select or Search Urdu then select Urdu Phonetic.
5. After It on the top right bottom there will be a sign like "en" click it.
6. Now you can change keyboard anytime.